# Opening a URL using the native PlayBook browser from an Android-based application

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-playbook, qnx

When a link is opened in a PlayBook application that runs in the Android JVM (that is, an Android app that's been ported to the PlayBook using the BlackBerry Plug-in for Android Development Tools), an Android WebView activity is launched to display the web page contents within the running application. From here, the user can select 'View in PlayBook Browser' from the PlayBook menu to open the URL in the native PlayBook browser.

Is it possible to bypass the Android WebView activity and open the URL using the native PlayBook browser?

An unsuccessful approach is documented on the BlackBerry Developer Support Forums:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Plug-in-for-Android/Possible-to-launch-a-URL-to-the-PlayBook-browser-from-an-Android/m-p/1629005

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to bypass the Android WebView activity and open the URL using the native PlayBook browser.
We can easily do this for android. But while running the same application on playbook we will unable to do this.
Even blackberry can reject our application if our application is redirecting any webview.